# how to implement tilt shift blur(like circle selective blur in instagram) in ios using coreimage framework

Tags: ios6, blur, core-image

I know that, this can be done using GPUImageFramework. But I want it done using CoreImageFramework. Any tutorial?

Answer (score 2):

Apple covers tilt-shift in the CoreImage Programming Guide: [Tilt-Shift Filter Recipe](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_filer_recipes/ci_filter_recipes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001185-CH4-SW17).

To adapt this method to a circle, you'd want to use a `CIRadialGradient` instead of two `CILinearGradient`s